# Unknown action The action 'index' could not be found for CarController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

I just get this error from my app but I don't know why it's happening.  Also, my app goes to a non-specified route (sorry if it is a lot of code).  This is my `routes.rb`:

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

   root :to => "user#index"
     resources :user do
     resources :car
   end

   get "user/new"
   post "user/create"
  get "user/:id" => "User#show"
end
```

Here is my user controller (I don't have problem here is only for refer):

```
Class UserController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @car.save
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

...my car controller:

```
class CarController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.car.create(params[:car])
    if @car.save
      redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @user.id
    else
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
  end
end
```

and this is part of my `html.erb`:

```
<h2>new car registration</h2>

  <%= form_for([@user, @user.car.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :brand %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :brand %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :color %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :color %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :model %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :model %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :year %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :year %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Create new car"%>
</p>
```

my index is only a test but it has this

```
<h1>WELCOME TO TANKING CONTROL ONLINE</h1>
<p>
  <strong>for new users </strong>
  <%= link_to 'sign up', :action => :new %>
</p>
```

and the form of user registration it this

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => { :action => :create } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <br>

  <%= link_to '<<Back', :action => :index %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: devise_for :users will take care of the user being created so no need for the user routes at the bottom.

Comment: i forget something i don't know why sometimes i get this error too 
    
    No route matches [POST] "/users/1/cars"

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an action 'index' in your CarController..

```
def index
end
```

Make sure you have an 'index.html.erb' in your 'cars' views.

[UPDATE] Your routes should be

```
resources :users do
  resources :cars
end
```

Notice the plurality of users and cars.

Comment: i did that but now i get a new error... must i open a new post?

Comment: The `def index...end` is not required if it will be empty; but the index template must exist.

Comment: @zabba Good point--I was assuming he meant to show something.

Comment: @zabba Good point. I've always thought it good practice to show the methods in the controller and had not tested it before to see if it was necessary, but your comment led me to check it out. You are right! I am surprised that the controller doesn't require the methods, but instead infers them from the existence of the files, which seems unusual.